# How to check Operating System Version on the roku device programmatically?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I need to get the OS version on the Roku device programmatically as I need to switch the playback url to Playready url or Widevine url based on OS version. Because Roku device can play Widevine encrypted content only if Roku OS is 8.1 or advanced.

We can use GetOSVersion() of roDeviceInfo to get this information but this API is available since Roku OS 9.2. Is there any other way to get the OS version running on the roku device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***GetVersion()*** of ***roDeviceInfo***. This will return a string of 13 characters, in which 3rd to 6th characters are major and minor number. You can get this substring using **Mid(string, start_position, substring_length)** function.

Answer (score 1):

From roDeviceinfo you got all the information about Roku device